# querying data via $wpdb and get_row

Tags: wp-query, database

I am using the Contact Form 7 Plugin to keep data of a form and I would like to query a table to show the results in a template. So this is what my query is:

```
global $wpdb;

$query = "SELECT count(*) as num 
            FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits a,wp_cf7dbplugin_submits b
            WHERE a.field_name = 'Buyer'
                AND a.field_value = 1 
                AND a.submit_time = b.submit_time 
                AND b.field_name = carbrand
                AND b.field_value='Mercedes'";

$results = $wpdb->get_row( $query, OBJECT );
var_dump( $results );
```

For some reason `var_dump()` spits out a `NULL` value. When i run the same query in mysql console I see the result that it is supposed to return 2.

Can anyone advise me on what I'm doing wrong? I went over The Codex to integrate `$wpdb` variable but I can't say I was successful...

Comment: Do you have debugging on? Maybe start with a simpler more basic query and work your way up to that point to find out where it specifically "breaks" ( returns null ). Also, note that questions regarding 3rd party plugins ( such as Contact Form 7 ) are considered to be [Off-Topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits a,wp_cf7dbplugin_submits b  WHERE a.field_name = 'Buyer' AND a.field_value = 1 AND a.submit_time = b.submit_time AND b.field_name = carbrand AND b.field_value='Mercedes'";

global $wpdb;
// return the number of rows found
$results = $wpdb->num_rows($query);
var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: what it is printing in $results

Comment: there is no output, i guess it is NULL

Comment: there is no output, i guess it is NULL, when i change $wpdb->num_rows($query) to $wpdb->get_col($query) or $wpdb->num_results($query) , i see array(0) { }